# Pyspark Series2Series UDF with Array of Structs as input and Struct as output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

How can I construct a UDF in spark which has nested (struct) input and output values for spark 3.0.1?

> NOTICE: I am aware of certain limitations of older versions of Arrow. This is why I am force installing pyarror >= 2 using conda, as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1644?src=confmacro was resolved recently. However, spark is not yet aware (fully supporting it).

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Timestamp
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set, struct, col
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("anomlydetection").master("local[4]").config("spark.driver.memory", "2G").getOrCreate()

metadata = pd.DataFrame({'meta_id': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5'}, 'value_a': {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 4, 4: 7}, 'time_start': {0: Timestamp('2020-08-12 04:29:24'), 1: Timestamp('2020-08-12 04:29:24'), 2: Timestamp('2020-08-12 04:29:24'), 3: Timestamp('2020-08-12 04:29:24'), 4: Timestamp('2020-08-12 04:29:24')}, 'time_end': {0: Timestamp('2020-08-12 10:22:23'), 1: Timestamp('2020-08-12 10:22:23'), 2: Timestamp('2020-08-12 10:22:23'), 3: Timestamp('2020-08-12 10:22:23'), 4: Timestamp('2020-08-12 10:22:23')}, 'value_b': {0: 15619415.0, 1: 15619415.0, 2: 15619415.0, 3: 15619415.0, 4: 15619415.0}})
metadata = spark.createDataFrame(metadata)
metadata = metadata.groupBy(["meta_id"]).agg(collect_set(struct(col("time_start"), col("time_end"), col("value_a"), col("value_b"))).alias("metadata"))

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2020-01-01 00:00', '2020-01-01 03:00', '2020-01-01 04:00', '2020-01-06 00:00'], 'category':['1','1','1','1'], 'value':[5, 8, 7, 2], 'meta_id':[1,2, np.NaN,5]})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df = df.join(metadata, ["meta_id"], "LEFT")
df.printSchema()
df.show(20, False)
```

looks like:

```
root
 |-- meta_id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |-- metadata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- time_start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- time_end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value_a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value_b: double (nullable = true)


-------+-------------------+--------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|meta_id|time               |category|value|metadata                                                    |
+-------+-------------------+--------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|NaN    |2020-01-01 04:00:00|1       |7    |null                                                        |
|1.0    |2020-01-01 00:00:00|1       |5    |[[2020-08-12 04:29:24, 2020-08-12 10:22:23, 6, 1.5619415E7]]|
|2.0    |2020-01-01 03:00:00|1       |8    |[[2020-08-12 04:29:24, 2020-08-12 10:22:23, 6, 1.5619415E7]]|
|5.0    |2020-01-06 00:00:00|1       |2    |[[2020-08-12 04:29:24, 2020-08-12 10:22:23, 7, 1.5619415E7]]|
+-------+-------------------+--------+-----+------------------------------------------------------------+

def s2s(time: pd.Series, metadata: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """We must use DataFrames to represent the structs"""
    # iterate over all the timestamp start/end and test for overlap with the time column.
    # matching logic is not implemented for sake of brevity
    # instead (and to better debug only a loop which prints the contents of metadata)
    print(metadata)
    if metadata is not None:
        for m in metadata:
            print(m)
    print('***')
    return pd.DataFrame({'overlap': False, 'overlap_value_a': -1, 'overlap_value_b':-1}, index=[0])

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf
s2s = pandas_udf(s2s, returnType=StructType())

df.select(s2s(col("time"), col("metadata"))).show()
```

fails with:

```
0    None
Name: _1, dtype: object
None
***
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

But I am already checking for NULLs inside - what is going wrong here?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame` is mapped to StructType, but metadata column is `array of StructType`, dont think this is supported with the current pandas_udf. you can probably convert the data type from array of structs into array of strings, for example: `metadata = metadata.groupBy("meta_id").agg(collect_set(concat_ws(',',"time_start","time_end", "value_a","value_b")).alias("metadata"))` and then in pandas, split them into 4 fields. Also if any of 4 columns have NULL, will need to do for example `coalease("time_start", "")`, so that fields aligned correctly after split.

Comment: I was hoping using Arrow 2.x should fix it - but you are probably right that spark itself is not *enough* aware of these new capabilities just yet.

Comment: Would it work is a regular UDF? I.e. Without arrow?

Comment: yes, in a regular UDF, StructType is converted into `Row` object, MapType to `dict` and ArrayType to a `list`. The combination of nested datatypes should be working as well.

Answer (score 0):

It works - you just have to use a pandas.DataFrame as the output and map appropriate types for the resulting struct/array.

Comment: @OP any chance you can your post your correct solution?